# How to open open window in new window from javascript using href in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, href

I have a following code where i am opening an external url link from my asp.net MVC view.

Now I have to add an entry when opening the link.
My thinking is that i should do it via some javascript function which will call ajax call to my web api controller and then open a new window of the url

```
 @{
            var token = Session["SecurityToken"] as AppSecurityToken;
            if (token != null && token.Claims != null)
            {
                foreach (var claim in token.Claims)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(claim.Description))
                    {
                        string imagepathv = Url.Content("~/") + "images/" + claim.Name + ".png";
                        string hreftext = $"{claim.Description}?sessionid={token.SessionId}";
                        <li>
                            <a href="" onclick="UserNameAccess('@hreftext');">
                                <img src="@imagepathv" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
            }
        }


<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function UserNameAccess(input) {
            window.open(input, "_blank");


            var baseSiteUrl = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiBaseUrl"]';
            var request = { "email": "sadasd", "firstname": "asdasd", "lastname": "dasdasda" };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseSiteUrl + "DataAccessApi/LogUserClaimAccesshistory",
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                datatype: "text",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (resultData) {
                    var responseJson = resultData;
                    if (responseJson.Success === true) {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("error1");
                    }
                },
                failure: function (error) {
                    alert(error);
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus) {

                    if (textStatus === 'timeout') {
                        alert("Request Timeout");
                        //do something. Try again perhaps?
                    } else {
                        alert(jqXhr.statusText);
                    }
                },
                timeout: 30000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
            });
        }
    </script>       


 public class DataAccessController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("DataAccessApi/LogUserClaimAccesshistory")]
        public MyJsonResponse LogUserClaimAccesshistory(UserClaimHistory request)
        {
            MyJsonResponse result = new MyJsonResponse();
            return result;
        }
    }   


    public class MyJsonResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public bool Success { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string CustomInfo { get; set; }
    }


    public class UserClaimHistory
    {
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("firstname")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastname")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to achieve nor *why* ... ?

Comment: On a href click call a web api  and then open a link

Comment: What web API ? how do you call it ? Do you use a library ? What does it return ?

Comment: If you need help about the way to call your API, please give us more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My code comes in  alert(error); section

Comment: What I have found out if i commented out the //window.open(input, "_blank"); my ajax funtion works other wise it doesn't.
Any idea I can work them together

Comment: Do you need to open the new window before or after the ajax call ? Or maybe the order doesn't matter ?

Comment: Ideally after the ajax call.But now i am putting off the idea of order.I have let the href let as it is

Comment: I think it is best this way. Using the `a` tag for what it was designed to do is the best way to keep readability for your code. glad i helped :-)

Comment: What i were thinking of doing some validation before opening the link in another window. But now have dropped the idea and followed KISS rule :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the below code ? Let the `a` tag do the web page opening, while the JS takes care of the API call.

Updated answer :

```
@{
    var token = Session["SecurityToken"] as AppSecurityToken;
    if(token != null && token.Claims != null)
    {
        foreach(var claim in token.Claims)
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(claim.Description))
            {
                string imagepathv = Url.Content("~/") + "images/" + claim.Name + ".png";
                string hreftext = $"{claim.Description}?sessionid={token.SessionId}";
                <li>
                    <!-- We use the <a> tag to handle the new page opening -->
                    <a href="@hreftext" onclick="UserNameAccess();" target="_blank">
                        <img src="@imagepathv"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
}

<!-- The javascript completly ignores the new page, and only focus on the API call -->
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function UserNameAccess()
    {
        var baseSiteUrl = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebApiBaseUrl"]';
        var request = { "email": "sadasd", "firstname": "asdasd", "lastname": "dasdasda" };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: baseSiteUrl + "DataAccessApi/LogUserClaimAccesshistory",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            datatype: "text",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(resultData)
            {
                var responseJson = resultData;
                if (responseJson.Success === true)
                {
                    alert("success");
                } else
                {
                    alert("error1");
                }
            },
            failure: function(error)
            {
                alert(error);
            },
            error: function(jqXhr, textStatus)
            {
                if (textStatus === 'timeout')
                {
                    alert("Request Timeout");
                    //do something. Try again perhaps?
                } else
                {
                    alert(jqXhr.statusText);
                }
            },
            timeout: 30000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
        });
    }
</script>
```